# Running code before every method in a class (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I want to keep track of all the methods which have been run on an instance of a class I've built.

Currently I do:

```
class MyClass
    def initialize
        @completed = []
    end

    # Sends a welcome and information pack to the person who requested it
    def one_of_many_methods
    unless @completed.include? __method__
            # Do methody things
            @completed.push __method__
        end
    end
    alias :another_name :one_of_many_methods
    # Calling myClassInstance.another_name will insert
    # :one_of_many_methods into @completed.
    # Methody things should not now be done if .another_name
    # or .one_of_many_methods is called.
end
```

But that gets very laborious when I have many methods in my class. I'm repeating myself! Is there a way to track the methods being called and to only allow them to be called once, like I'm doing above, but without having to repeat that block in every method?

Thanks!

(PS. I'm using Ruby 1.9)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect use case for a [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) object. Fortunately, Ruby's dynamic nature makes implementing it quite easy:

```
class ExecuteOnceProxy

  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
    @completed = []
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    unless @completed.include?(method)
      args.empty? ? @obj.send(method) : @obj.send(method, args)
      @completed << method
    end
  end
end
```

Initialize your proxy simply by passing the original object in the constructor:

```
proxy = ExecuteOnceProxy.new(my_obj)
```

Comment: +1. JP, I would recommend checking out [Design Patterns in Ruby](http://designpatternsinruby.com/), it covers many common design patters in Ruby, including the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

#### [method_missing](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Kernel.html#M001069)

---

There are frameworks that will do things like this but to answer your question, yes, there is an easy way.

And the easy way to only writing the code once is to front-end the entire class and implement [method_missing.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Kernel.html#M001069) You can then uncover the real methods one at a time as each is discovered to be "missing" with an initial call.

Comment: I get this technique, but I don't get what you mean by front-ending. Can you give an example of this?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is new solution for your question.

Some times ago, Tobias Pfeiffer released [after_do](https://github.com/PragTob/after_do) gem

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer because I do not have enough reputation to comment but please note that the answer @emboss posted has an error in it (missing star).

`args.empty? ? @obj.send(method) : @obj.send(method, args)`

should be

`args.empty? ? @obj.send(method) : @obj.send(method, *args)`

otherwise the method will receive a single arg: an array of the args you tried to pass it.